# Filtar mensajes por id de usuario sin Accion bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, recyclerview

```html
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mostrar_mensaje);
        misMensajes = findViewById(R.id.Recycler);

        LayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        misMensajes.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager);

        resultado = new ArrayList<>();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        String id  = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");


        db.collection("mensaje")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentos:task.getResult()){
                                String id = documentos.getId();
                                String mensaje = documentos.getData().get("mensaje").toString();
                                resultado.add(new Mensaje(id, mensaje));
                            }
                            myAdaptador = new AdaptadorComplejo(resultado);
                            misMensajes.setAdapter(myAdaptador);
                        }
                        else{
                            Log.e("MensajeApp", "Error", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });

    }
```

En mi RecyclerView al momento de mostar los mensajes solo quiero que se muestren los mensajes de un determinado usuario el que esta dado por  ''String id  = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id")''; la cual trae el id del usuario que inicio la sesión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y para que el visualize todos sus mensajes de el en el Firebase en los documentos de mensaje esta esta el id del usuario ¿Como puedo hacer para que solo se muestre los mesajes del Usuario de Incio la sesion (id)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo unico que necesitas es agregar un `whereEqualTo` a la consulta

```
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
String id  = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
db.collection("mensaje").whereEqualTo("idUsuario", id).get()
```